# Lost connection to MySQL server during query in large data

Tags: mysql

In my mysql database I've Orderhead and Orderline tables along with other tables. Orderhead contains 37700 and Orderline contains 965093 rows.
My query to grab orderline is as follows

```
SELECT * FROM Orderline 
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT UUID FROM Orderhead WHERE 1 AND Orderhead.InsertTime >= '0001-01-01 00:00:00' AND Employee = 'TK' AND TYPE NOT IN ('WebShop')
) AS `Orderhead` ON `Orderline`.`OrderUUID` = `Orderhead`.`UUID` ORDER BY Orderline.Number
```

Query return 19962 rows.But very offten it is throwing error "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" from app.In query window (SQLyog)
when i run the query sometime it takes 45 sec, sometime 5 second(although i tried SQL_NO_CACHE,RESET QUERY CACHE, FLUSH QUERY CACHE for not considering cache).
i am not sure how much performance benefit i get by using IN or EXISTS Keyword.

```
In---

SELECT  * FROM Orderline 
WHERE `Orderline`.`OrderUUID` IN 
(
  SELECT UUID FROM Orderhead WHERE 1 AND Orderhead.InsertTime >= '0001-01-01 00:00:00' AND Employee = 'TK' AND TYPE NOT IN ('WebShop')
) ORDER BY Orderline.Number

Exists---

SELECT * FROM Orderline 
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT UUID FROM Orderhead WHERE 1 AND Orderhead.InsertTime >= '0001-01-01 00:00:00' AND Employee = 'TK' AND TYPE NOT IN ('WebShop') 
  AND `Orderline`.`OrderUUID` = `Orderhead`.`UUID`
) ORDER BY Orderline.Number
```

i also increase net_read_timeout,connect_timeout, max_allowed_packet as the link said https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html,
but no luck.i run these from SQLyog query window.New incremented value is set.But no luck.Should i need to restart the server to take effect?

Which one is best among JOIN, In & Exists? How can i add Index(on which fields) for best Optimization?
How can i run query without considering cache?

Comment: I would suggest posting the table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE Orderline`) for every table involved in the question.. And explain (`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Orderline ...`) of the query here because this is a optimisation/performance related question.

Comment: What human being is capable of reading 19 thousand records at once? Why would you return that many in the first place? The solution is not increasing limits, it's figuring out what exactly are you doing and whether that's what's needed. While returning 19k records is doable, the question is - why?